# Бот телеграмм не реагирует на команды

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Делаю бота по данной инструкции - https://djdiplomat.ru/kak-napist-telegram-bot-na-php
Все создалось и зарегистрировал, вродебы без ошибок - но бот не реагирует на команды - подскажите в чем ошибка может быть?
Хостинг обычный.

Comment: Может логами с ошибками поделитесь. Тяжело так диагностировать.

Comment: Ошибок как таковых нет, может проблема в том что у меня сертификат небезопасный? в этом может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Все заработало - проблема была в сертификате !
Активировал - и все пошло!